# How to deploy apps made by titanium studio? In both app store and android market. What are the things to do for that?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, appcelerator-mobile

I am new to Titanium studio. I was working in X-code before this. I have some questions to be asked. If my questions are cleared, then I would like to purchase a membership from Appcelerator for development. Please give me the details about the deployment of the apps in iPhone and android....

1. Is this like "write once and run in both android and iOS platforms"?
2. Do we have to do any extra things beyond the Titanium studio to run the same code in both the frameworks?
3. Do we have to do any extra things beyond the Titanium studio to put the apps in appstore or to deploy in the device?
4. What will be final output of the application?( will it be the same like in Xcode? if not please give details)

Please give me the full details in order to clarify my doubts.

Thanking You Sreekumar K U

Comment: I haven't worked much on Titanium studio but can give you some of the answers

Once you have written your whole code for application you will simply get the .apk for android and .ipa for iphone so you can upload them on their respective markets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the answer I [got from Kami on the Appcelerator Developer Center](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121821/how-to-deploy-apps-made-by-titanium-studio-in-both-app-store-and-android-market-what-are-the-things-to-do-for-that#answer-211815):

> - Its not entirely write once and run on both platforms, even tho titanium does a great job at making the same code work for both
>     platforms.  An iPhone just is not an Android. In most cases you will
>     need to make seperate code sections for Android and iPhone. Which is
>     not difficult to make. Just look at the titanium kitchensink project.
>     This will learn you the basic with ease and shows you what titanium is
>     capable of.
> - Also tweetanium, a twitter app made in titanium, is 1 app that works great on both iPhone and Android. Its an open source app so you could
>     look into their code for examples.
> - There arent more steps to deploy or run on device. I havent gone to the studio version. But there will always remain an xcode project in
>     the build folder. This you can open and then run on device or make an
>     .ipa file the way you do it normally.
> - This one im still not 100% sure, but in the end you have an exacutable in Xcode and Java. Titanium compiles javascript code to
>     their native code. If i recall on iPhone this was done on run time,
>     but not so sure about that.
>
> Correct me if im wrong somewhere, whole lot of info.